# In Jax-RS is there a way to get a header value without having to specify @HeaderParam in every call

Tags: java, jax-rs

I know there will be a certain header value in every call. I have a BaseService that builds responses and does other things, however it doesn't inherit from anything at the moment.

I would like to add `getHeaderValue()` to it and have it available in all classes. Is there a way I can do that from a filter or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>I have no Idea what this has to do with Jackson. I'm assuming you are using JAX-RS, as this is the only place that I know `@HeaderParam` exists.</s> What you can do, is make use of `HttpHeaders`. Depending what version of JAX-RS you are using, the implementation will be a little different. Here is [JAX-RS 1.1 version](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/core/HttpHeaders.html), and here is [JAX-RS 2.0 version](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/HttpHeaders.html). The only thing really of interest that may matter to you is that the 2.0 version has a [`getHeaderString(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/HttpHeaders.html#getHeaderString%28java.lang.String%29) method that returns a single String value. In 1.1, you will need to make use of [`getRequestHeader(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/core/HttpHeaders.html#getRequestHeader%28java.lang.String%29), which actually returns a `List<String>`. The reason is that a header may appear more than once.

In any case, you can inject the `HttpHeaders` into your "base"/abstract resource class. Then just have a method to obtain a cartain header and/or a method that accepts a String and allows the caller the specify the header they want. For instance

```
public abstract class BaseResource<T> {
    @Context
    protected HttpHeaders headers;

    protected String getCertainHeader() {
        return headers.getHeaderString("Certain-Header");
    }

    protected String getHeader(String headerName) {
        return headers.getHeaderString(headerName);
    }
}

@Path("/foo")
public class FooResource extends BaseResource<Foo> {

    @GET
    public Response getSomething() {
        String certainHeader = getCertainHeader();
    }
}
```

Comment: You're right. That was a mistake in the title. And this is exactly what I need. Thanks!